# OutlinedTextField placeholder, not changing color in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, outlined-text-fields

I've been trying to get the placeholder text inside of an OutlinedTextField to change color and it is just staying black, no matter what I do. I am using M3 theme and components. I can get everything else to change (text color, border color, etc), just not the placeholder. In my Color.kt file I define all the colors, one of them being onSurface...

```
val md_theme_dark_onSurface = Color(red = 140, green = 207, blue = 242)
```

Then in my LoginView.kt I am trying to use that to tell the placeholder what color to be...

```
val textFieldColor = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
  focusedPlaceholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
  unfocusedPlaceholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
)
```

Then set the colors of the outlined text field...

```
OutlinedTextField(
  value = uiState.username,
  keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
  onValueChange = { viewModel.setUsername(it) },
  placeholder = { Text("Username") },
  leadingIcon = {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.user), contentDescription = null)
  },
  colors = textFieldColor
)
```

One would think that would change the placeholder in the text field, but it does not. I still get a black placeholder. The border and image are correctly colored and change when focused/unfocused but the placeholder stays black, even in Dark theme.

[image]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

use this code, tested its working

```
   OutlinedTextField(
        value ="hello",
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
        onValueChange = {"ssss"},
        placeholder = { Text("Username") },
        leadingIcon = {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp), contentDescription = null)
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedPlaceholderColor = Color.Red,
            unfocusedTextColor = Color.Green

        )
    )
```